# Rails Spec Controller Test failing with custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Rails 5.1
RSpec 3.6

I have a Controller:

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
end
```

A custom route:

```
get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
```

RSpec Test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SessionController, type: :controller do

  describe "GET #new" do
      before do
        routes.draw { get "login" => "sessions#new" }
      end

    it "returns http success" do
      get :login
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

and get error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"login", :controller=>"session"}
```

So "get" within a controller test seems always map to the action not the route. What should i do to get this test run? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing tests and you use the methods get, post, delete, etc., those methods assume that any parameter you pass them is the name of an action within the controller being tested. So, this works:

```
get :new
```

because it generates url_for(:controller => :sessions, :action => :new).

This doesn't work:

```
get '/login'
```

because it generates `url_for(:controller => :sessions, :action => '/login')`.

Answer (score 1):

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches
>   {:action=>"login", :controller=>"session"}

Your controller name is `SessionController`, so your route should be

`get 'login' => 'session#new'` not `get 'login' => 'sessions#new'`

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe SessionController, type: :controller do

  describe "GET #new" do
    before do
      routes.draw { get "login" => "session#new" }
    end

    it "returns http success" do
      get :login
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

Change it in your `routes.rb` as well.

Comment: after correcting name session to sessions ( SessionsController) problem remains the same:     ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"login", :controller=>"sessions"}

Comment: thanks! i think, i was confused by the term "get" because it does not invoke a route in this context but an action.